# Writing javascript in the codemirror source view of froala, then switching back to visual mode, causes the javascript to execute

Tags: jquery, html, codemirror, froala

When using [froala 2.3.4](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor), I found some issues where it stripped out a bunch of valid code such as `<script>` and `<style>` tags, custom html tags (fictional ones like `<foo>`) as well as generally reformatting the code to 'beautify it.

After some playing around, I got it working so that (so far) the code remains relatively untouched, however in testing a `<script>` block, I noticed when switching back from code view, that it actually EXECUTED the code that I just wrote inside the [CodeMirror 5.8.12](http://codemirror.net/) box (see screenshot)

[image: froala codemirror]

Here is the code I am using to initialize CodeMirror and froala :

```
function completeAfter(cm, pred) {
    var cur = cm.getCursor();
    if (!pred || pred()) setTimeout(function() {
        if (!cm.state.completionActive)
            var doc = cm.getDoc();
            var POS = doc.getCursor();
            var mode = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), cm.getTokenAt(POS).state).mode.name;
            //  console.log(mode);
            if (mode == 'xml') { //html depends on xml
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.html);
            } else if (mode == 'javascript') {
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.javascript);
            } else if (mode == 'css') {
                CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.css);
            }
    }, 100);
    return CodeMirror.Pass;
}

function completeIfAfterLt(cm) {
    return completeAfter(cm, function() {
        var cur = cm.getCursor();
        return cm.getRange(CodeMirror.Pos(cur.line, cur.ch - 1), cur) == "<";
    });
}

function completeIfInTag(cm) {
    return completeAfter(cm, function() {
        var tok = cm.getTokenAt(cm.getCursor());
        if (tok.type == "string" && (!/['"]/.test(tok.string.charAt(tok.string.length - 1)) || tok.string.length == 1)) return false;
        var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), tok.state).state;
        return inner.tagName;
    });
}

var codeHeight = 'calc(100vh - 96px)';
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
    codeHeight = '-o-' + codeHeight;
} else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {
    codeHeight = '-webkit-' + codeHeight;
} else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    codeHeight = '-webkit-' + codeHeight;
} else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {
    codeHeight = '-moz-' + codeHeight;
}

$('.code').froalaEditor({
  theme: 'dark',
  height: codeHeight,
  htmlAllowedTags: ['.*'],
  htmlRemoveTags: [''],
  htmlAllowedAttrs: ['.*'],
  htmlAllowedEmptyTags: ['*'],
  codeMirrorOptions: {
    mode: "htmlmixed",
    lineNumbers: true,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    foldGutter: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    theme: 'icecoder',
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-foldgutter", "CodeMirror-linenumbers"],
    autocomplete: true,
    extraKeys: {
        "'<'": completeAfter,
        "'/'": completeIfAfterLt,
        "' '": completeIfInTag,
        "'='": completeIfInTag,
        "'.'": completeAfter,
        "'{'": completeAfter,
        "':'": completeAfter,
        "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"
    }
  }
});
```

For CodeMirror, I have the following plugins/etc bundled from [codemirror minification helper](http://codemirror.net/doc/compress.html) as `codemirror-extras.js` { `codemirror.js` is not selected as part of the bundle as it breaks when doing it using the following modules from the minification helper so it is kept separate }:

```
Modes:
- css.js
- htmlembedded.js
- htmlmixed.js
- javascript.js
- smarty.js
- xml.js
Add-ons:
- active-line.js
- brace-fold.js
- closebrackets.js
- closetag.js
- comment-fold.js
- css-hint.js
- css-lint.js
- dialog.js
- foldcode.js
- foldgutter.js
- html-hint.js
- html-lint.js
- indent-fold.js
- javascript-hint.js
- matchbrackets.js
- matchtags.js
- overlay.js
- search.js
- searchcursor.js
- show-hint.js
- sql-hint.js
- xml-fold.js
- xml-hint.js
```

How can I prevent the code I write in the "view source" tab when the viewer of said tab is CodeMirror 5.8.12 inside froala from executing when switching back by toggling the "view source" (    }   button - while also ensuring that said adjustment does not break the continuity between froala and CodeMirror ?

Answer (score 0):

On summernote.js search the line:

```
$editable.html(dom.html($note) || dom.emptyPara);
```

and replace it with:

```
var str = dom.html($note) || dom.emptyPara;
str = str.replace('<script>', '<scriptfalse>');
str = str.replace('<script ', '<scriptfalse ');
str = str.replace('</script>', '</scriptfalse>');
$editable.html(str);
```

And also search the line:

```
$note.val(context.invoke('code'));
```

and replace it with:

```
var str = context.invoke('code');
str = str.replace('<scriptfalse>', '<script>');
str = str.replace('<scriptfalse ', '<script ');
str = str.replace('</scriptfalse>', '</script>');
$note.val(str);
```